# Python SMTP Issue with Gmail

Tags: python, windows, gmail, smtplib

Did anything change with gmail SMTP? I was able to use it to send emails a few months ago.  However, I have tried the following code and I get a timeout error every time:

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

I have also tried

```
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

and I still get a timeout error.  I have also tried port 465.  Almost all posts or articles about using smtplib to connect to gmail are from a long time ago.  Did anything change recently?

I checked and incoming connections are set as disabled for python on my machine's firewall.  However, I also tried the same code from a server that does not have any firewall settings involving python and I get [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I am on windows.

Comment: This `s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, timeout=10)` works on my side, is there any corporate firewall between you and gmail? Possibly a proxy? Some meddling with the SSL certificate which makes it invalid? Actually, was there **any recent change in your network recently**?

Comment: Ah rats.  Yeah I'm behind a corporate firewall.  I was kind of hoping it was something else but they probably just changed firewall settings.  thanks for your prompt response